# Save checked checkboxes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, checkbox

I have a Website at work which is being used As a settings page. It contains about 200 checkboxes. Is there an easy way to somehow Save the checkboxes which are checked and send them to a coworker for him to be able to automaticaly get the correct settigns? I was able to find a javascript which after enterin in the adress bar checked/unchecked all and thought that there might be an elegant way to check the needed ones instantly.

Comment: Show us an example of what you're doing with some code. Also, you'd need to first define what 'custom' boxes you want checked for JavaScript to check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty hacky, and all console based, but you could do something like this...

Each checkbox would have to have a name... or replace name for id...

```
var arr = [];
$('input:checked').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Then you could take the output of `arr` and give him that with a short script to check the boxes.

```
var arr = ["name1"];
arr.forEach(function(v){
    $('input[name="'+v+'"]').prop('checked',true);
});
```

I hope this helps.